# Magento 2: Prevent "Add to Cart" Error Message Autohide

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, messages, ajaxaddtocart

On product page, if you try to put more than available product count into the shopping cart, there appears a red error message

```
"The requested qty is not available"
```

thats good.

But in my magento 2.3.2 this message gets hidden after 5 seconds = too quickly, so user maybe does not see it.

***I want to disable this feature or enlarge the time to about 15 seconds. Can someone please help me to do this?***

I've looked into so many .js and other files, try to watch via Developer Console which script is firing but no success.

This add to cart message is DIFFERENT than the ones in the checkout. For the checkout ones I've found the solution to look into

```
/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/frontend/web/js/view/messages.js
```

where you can enlarge the time for the ***"checkout error messages"***, but its not helping for add to cart problems.

Anyone any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that for Cart page, its not from JS.

Kindly check the below php files that throws the error "The requested qty is not available"

> magento/module-catalog-inventory/Model/StockStateProvider.php
>
> magento/module-requisition-list/Model/RequisitionListItem/Validator/Stock.php